# Divide a number in unequal increasing parts according to a dynamic factor

Tags: arithmetic

There is a game where you need to gather money from people participating to it and when you have the total you need to divide it in order to put a "reasonable amount" for each of the `n` prizes they will be able to win.

E.g. in general we usually make the calcution approximately, so in case you have a total of 8$ (`t = 8`) and 5 prizes (`n = 5`) we could divide the total into:

- prize 1: `0.8$`
- prize 2: `1.2$`
- prize 3: `1.5$`
- prize 4: `1.9$`
- prize 5: `2.6$`

As you can see it would be important to have prize `n` to be "more important" than prize 1, in general.

I would like to find a rule to obtain those prize values dynamically according to:

- `t = total amount of money`
- `n = number of prizes`
- `y = a variable factor to provide in order to abtain different combinations of prize values, in a way that a lower 'y' value means being more "fair" in giving values to prizes, on the contrary a higher 'y' value means increasing the difference between prize 1 and prize 'n'`

E.g. in case I want to be more "fair" a possibility would be:

- prize 1: `1.2$`
- prize 2: `1.4$`
- prize 3: `1.6$`
- prize 4: `1.8$`
- prize 5: `2.0$`

or

- prize 1: `1.1$`
- prize 2: `1.2$`
- prize 3: `1.5$`
- prize 4: `2.0$`
- prize 5: `2.2$`

but I really have no idea about what formula or algorithm I could use to make that calculation by simply having as input (`y`, `n` and `t`) and how to be able to provide a `y` factor to use in order to vary the resulting prize values.

Any idea about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

Set the $k$th prize to be 
$$
C r^{k-1}
$$
for some value of $C$, 
where $r = 1 + y$. For $y = 0$, you get all prizes the same; for $y = 1$, each prize is *double* the previous one. For $y = 0.1$, you get something like the values you had.

Of course, to complete this, I have to give a value for $C$. But we know that the sum of all the prizes has to be 
$$
C(1 + r + \ldots + r^{n-1}) = C \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}
$$
and we want this sum to be the total $t$. That means that 
$$
C = t \frac{1-r}{1-r^n}.
$$
The formula for the $k$th prize, where $k$ goes from $1$ to $n$ is thus 
\begin{align}
p_k &= t\, r^{k-1} \frac{1-r}{1-r^n}\\
&= t\, (1+y)^{k-1} \frac{y}{(1+y)^n - 1}
\end{align}

If I were writing a program, I'd compute $r = 1+y$ first, and then use the first form rather than the second, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: thank you! I tried to compute it (in javascript):
`var prizes = 5;
var factor = 0.2;
var prizeValues = [];
var money = 0;
for (var k = 1; k <= prizes; k++) {
  var calc = (prizes * ((1 + factor) ^ (k - 1))) * (factor / (((1 + factor) ^ prizes) - 1));
  prizeValues.push(calc);
  money += calc;
}
console.warn(prizeValues);
console.warn(money);`

but the result is: `[0.3333333333333333, 0, 1, 0.6666666666666666, 1.6666666666666667]` and total money is `3.666666666666667`.
What if I want to avoid `o` as value for a `k`?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the total of the prizes is the same as the number of prizes because you use $n$ for both.  I don't think that is intended.  It would be good to use a different variable for one of them.

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry I did not understand your point. What is my mistake? Thank you

Comment: In the first display equation you have $n$ terms in the sum on the left, which represents $n$ prizes.  Then you say you want the total to be $n$.  In the original post there were $5$ prizes totaling $8$, so one of the two uses of $n$ should be changed to a different variable.  OP uses $t$ for the total of the prizes.  This just scales the equation by $\frac tn$, not a big deal.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks. So, in case I have `8` as total amount of money and `5` as total number of prizes how do I rewrite the formulate that @JohnHughes provided?

Comment: Yes, it becomes $C=t\frac {1-r}{1-r^n}$ with $n=5,t=8$

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok I edited my code above and I have `var calc = (totalMoney * ((1 + factor) ^ (k - 1))) * (factor / (((1 + factor) ^ prizes) - 1));` with `var totalMoney = 8;`. Still, when I run it I get `[ 0.5333333333333333, 0, 1.6, 1.0666666666666667, 2.6666666666666665 ]` and `5.866666666666667` so I have a `0` that I would not want and the total `money` is `5.866666666666667` but I expected it to be `8` at the end no? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87694/discussion-between-frank-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: I've edited to make the sum of prizes be $t$ instead of $n$. Sorry for going on vacation and leaving a mess for you to clean up, @RossMillikan.

Comment: @Frank how did you fix the code?

Comment: ok I fixed it, @JohnHughes amazing man thanks thumbs up and upvoted